# Number of colorings of cube's faces

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to color faces of a cube with N colors if 
two colorings are the same if it's possible to rotate the cube such that
one coloring goes to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of different colorings is equal to

\begin{equation*}
\frac{n^6 + 3n^4 + 12n^3 + 8n^2}{24}.
\end{equation*}

You can get this number using [Burnside lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_lemma).
The wikipedia article contains solution of your problem as well.