# Formal counting of cube faces colorings wrt full symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, symmetry, platonic-solids

How many 3-colorings of cube's faces exist if we consider two colorings the same iff it's possible to **rotate and/or mirror** the cube such that one coloring goes to another?

I do know a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/number-of-colorings-of-cubes-faces) considering *only the rotations* was asked here. I do understand where the solution comes from: Burnside's lemma and the geometrical classification of cube rotations (by face, by edge, by vertex, etc). But I can't seem to construct a convenient geometrical classification of all the symmetries (is there really a sensible geometrical approach to this problem???)

I sense that the full symmetry group of a cube is $S_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$ since we can fix an arbitrary mirroring and combine it with all the rotations of the cube (which form a group isomorphic to $S_4$). I have heard of a solution which uses an embedding $S_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow S_6$ which "realizes all cube symmetries in permutations of cube's faces". I though have no idea how to build such an embedding and how can it help?

Basically I am looking for **any** approach to this problem which doesn't involve calculating $\text{Fix}(g)$ for all of the 48 cube symmetries $g$ separately and plugging it in Burnside's lemma (this is going to be on a test with limited time, so that is not acceptable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation group permutes the four diagonals, whence $S_4$. The rotations and index two in the full subgroup, since reflection x reflection = rotation, and the central involution $-I_3$ commutes with everything so we find the full symmetry group is $S_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Anyway, the conjugacy classes of rotations in $S_4$ are:

- $1~$ - $~0^{\circ}$ rotation
- $6~$ - $~90^{\circ}$ rotations around face axes
- $8~$ - $120^{\circ}$ rotations around vertex axes
- $3~$ - $180^{\circ}$ rotations around face axes
- $6~$ - $180^{\circ}$ rotations around edge axes

It's also a good exercise to figure out the cycle types in $S_4$ corresponding to each item above.

The other possibilities are plane reflections and rotation-reflections (which are reflections across planes combined with rotation in said planes). Here's a list:

- $3$ coordinate plane reflections
- $3$ coordinate plane reflections + $180^{\circ}$ rotation
- $6$ coordinate plane reflections + $90^{\circ}$ rotation
- $6$ antipodal-edge plane reflections
- $6$ antipodal-edge plane reflections + $180^{\circ}$ rotation

Finding $\mathrm{Fix}(g)$ for these $g$s should be doable.